# Index with multiple matches works in similar situations

Tags: excel-2010

I'm trying to use this formula (FX2):
{=INDEX(B1:D5,MATCH(1,(A1:A5=E4)*(B1:D1=E5),0),1)}
I have used it before in other workbooks before with the only change being second match looking at a column instead of row.
I could go with FX1 which works but would be hard to maintain or update:
=INDEX(B1:D5,MATCH(E4,A1:A5,0),1)
I can't for the life of me figure out why FX2 is not working please help. Sample data is below.
     A            B            C           D        E
1             12/26/2016     1/2/2017   1/9/2017
2             WK 52          WK 1        WK 2
3             50             750         473
4 SPHJ327SLV  20000          12          31       SPHJ327SLV
5             0              12          31       12/26/2016

Answer (score 0):

This formula worked:=INDEX(B1:D5,MATCH(E4,A1:A5,0),MATCH(E5,B1:D1,0))